# Comparing a list with other lists and then storing the result in case of a match in a new list

Tags: c, list, compare, store

What if I take a text file which contains  a list of words and I want this list to be compared with a number of lists(already sourced to the program)means if any word in the input list matches with a word in any of the sourced list I want that word to be stored in file a.txt only if the word was found in list1.txt). similarly if the word is found in list2.txt I want it to be stored in b.txt. Along with that I want to display the path of the file list1.txt in the output file a.txt. 
Like 
sing ./dataset/dictionary/verb

I have used the syntax below

```
while(dictcount >= 0)//reads dictionary word into array//
{   
    dictcount = 0; //searches through all of the listed data files
    fscanf(fp1,"%s", worddict);
    fscanf(fp2,"%s", worddict);
    fscanf(fp3,"%s", worddict);
    if(strcmp(wordcheck, worddict)==0)//compare strings//if the word in found in list misc.txt
    {
        fprintf(out_file1 ,"%c", wordcheck); //storing the value in output_misc.txt
        if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL)
        //fprintf(out_file3, "%c\n", cwd); //stores the path of the folder containing the list in which the matched 'word' is found  
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are we to assume there is logic to the madness of an `fprintf()` call that ultimately demotes a pointer *value* (`wordcheck`) to a char (`%c`), writing said-char to an output file?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use "EOF" to read file?
There is a problem that similar yours.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/459823f5-e5a7-46a4-9192-d607be0747f3/

Comment: beginning is similar but then that solution go down to a totally different road